# Add custom property to string

Tags: javascript

I often use function meta properties, i.e. like this

```
var func = function(){}
func.meta = "meta";
console.log(func);//output: function func()
console.log(func.meta);//output: "meta"
```

But when I tried using strings in similar way, it did't work.

```
var string = "string";
string.meta = "meta";
console.log(string);//output: "string"
console.log(string.meta);//output: undefined
```

Why and how to fix that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your string is a primitive value. It accepts the property because of some magic which temporarily converts it to an object (or you can think of it that way). So the assignment isn't useful after that.

You could use the `new String` constructor to create an object you can actually hold on to, but that's very unusual for JavaScript.

```
var string = new String("string");
string.meta = "meta";
console.log(string);
console.log(string.meta);//output: "meta"
```

The console output on the `string` itself will actually probably not show what you want, but in practice it should work in concatenation as such.

Keep in mind that `typeof` will no longer give you `"string"` as a result. It will now be `"object"`.

Personally, I'd just create a custom constructor if you need to store more than the string itself and then use it with the knowledge that the object is composed of your string and the meta data.

Comment: @zeroflagL: Did you not finish to the end of the sentence? In any case, that's a useful way of thinking of property access on  primitives in JS. Even the spec can't tell you exactly what an implementation does.

Comment: Let me rephrase my statement: In ECMAScript 5 an object might actually be created, but _"An implementation might choose to avoid the actual creation of that transient object"_. As for ECMAScript 2015 I agree with the last statement of your comment. Btw: the created property can actually be used: `console.log((string.meta = "meta"))` will log "meta".

Comment: @zeroflagL: Just a reminder that this is a community wiki. You're very much welcome to make improvements to it as you see fit. :-) However, `console.log((string.meta = "meta"))` isn't using the property; it's using the return value of the assignment expression.